# Why this slicing throws IndexError?

Tags: python, list

My code to search for words on a diagram goes as it follows:

```
size = len(word)
height = len(diagram)
width = len(diagram[0])
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        if (diagram[i][j] == word[0]):
            if (i + size < height):
                print(i, size, i+size, height)
                test = diagram[i:(i+size)][j]
            (...)
```

The print shows

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Searching for the word

```
hi
```

On the following diagram:

```
x x x x
x x h x
x i x x
x x x x
```

Or, in list form:

```
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'h', 'x'], ['x', 'i', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
```

It throws an **IndexError: list index out of range** on the slicing. I can't understand why, since [i, (i+size-1)] = [1, 2] is inside list bounds [0, 4].

Comment: FWIW, slice indexing never raises `IndexError`. Eg, `[1,2,3][1:100]` gives `[2, 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `test = diagram[i:(i+size)][j]` you do not get the index error on `[i:(i+size)]` but on `[j]`. After slicing, `diagram[i:(i+size)]` is a list of two lists, and `j` is `2`, thus *that* index is out of bounds.

Also note that the `[j]` will index into that list of lists, not into the individual lists, i.e. it will get you a row, not a column of the diagram. Most likely, you need a list comprehension of the slice, getting the `j`th element of each row:

```
test = [line[j] for line in diagram[i:(i+size)]]
```

Or you could use `numpy` and it's multi-dimensional slicing:

```
import numpy as np
diagram = np.array(diagram)
```

and then use `[...,...]` instead of `[...][...]`:

```
test = diagram[i:(i+size),j]
```

But this does not really allow to extract diagonals from the matrix, as seems to be needed for finding the word (assuming that that's what you want). For this, you could again use list comprehension and combine them with `enumerate` to get the position of the current letter and offset it accordingly:

```
test = [line[j-c] for c, line in enumerate(diagram[i:(i+size)])]
# ['h', 'i']
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Python and thought that it might interpret a list of lists as a matrix, therefore the lists would be sliced vertically. I get now that, for searching words on the vertical, it's better the old fashioned way (using loops). This works on horizontal, tho.

Comment: @LeandroMagalhães That's exactly what `numpy` does, see the last part of my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm helping a friend with this is college subject that doesn't allow anyone to use custom libraries, so I'll have to keep the first way. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2):

It's specifically because you're slicing. First, realize that what you have isn't necessarily a matrix; it's a list that happens to hold lists. When we slice a list, we get a copy of a portion of that list.

```
test = diagram[i:(i+size)][j]
```

So here you've extracted the portion `i:i+size` of `diagram`; this looks something like `[['x', 'x', 'h', 'x'], ['x', 'i', 'x', 'x']]`. Your second indexing is now operating in an offset and restricted space on the first axis, not the second axis, so in this example indices `2` and above are invalid. Even if it succeeded, it would produce an entire row, not a single character.